# Why are some core Perl modules also available on CPAN?

Tags: perl, cpan

For example I believe that the Encode module is considered a core module and shipped with every copy of Perl. It has its own page on Perldoc:

https://perldoc.perl.org/Encode.html

...but it is also available on CPAN:

http://search.cpan.org/~dankogai/Encode-2.92/Encode.pm

From skimming the two documents, it seems that they contain the same text. So why put it in both places? Is it just so that CPAN can be used to lookup documentation on "any Perl module"?

Comment: Being bundled with the default installation of Perl doesn't make a module any less of a module. Core modules also change over time.

Comment: One good thing about it is that some CPAN-style information is then right there, for instance the source.  Much harder to dig out of a perl distribution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Such modules are said to be "dual-life" modules.

- So users can upgrade the module without upgrading `perl` itself.
- So developers can release fixes and updates to the module on a different schedule (e.g. more often) than `perl` itself.
- Or maybe the module started on CPAN, and it was later added to the `perl` distro (e.g. because a module in the tool chain requires it).
- Or maybe the module is in the process of being removed from the Perl distro.

Comment: Perhaps add a blurb that some modules are dual-life, but then sometimes get removed from core (eg: `CGI), and maybe something about `corelist` on how to check if a module is core?

Comment: @stevieb, Mentioned the former. The latter might be a related topic, but has nothing to do with the question. If someone hasn't already asked that question, feel free to ask it (and optionally answer it) yourself.

Comment: Is there an easy way to see the schedule when certain modules were made core / removed from core?

Comment: Gotcha. Well in any case looks like corelist is my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Also making a core library available at CPAN allows to easily upgrade from the version shipped with Perl to get the latest improvements and bug fixes.

For example, `Encode` versions shipped with some versions of perl:

```
Perl      Encode
v5.22.4   2.72_01
v5.24.2   2.80_01
v5.26.1   2.88
```

(retrieved with `corelist -a Encode`). Any of these can be readily updated to the latest Encode 2.92.